# Need Explaining on isset for $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get, isset

i'm fighting here trying to understand the logic with the isset logical test for the $_GET. This is actually the answer from an exercise.

So it's this part:

```
if(isset($_GET['status']) && in_array($_GET['status'], $options)){
  $sql .= " WHERE status = ?";
  $execute = array($_GET['status']);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if the answers would be **//inline**, thanks alot.

1.) I understand that we are trying to see if status is not null, but why twice for $options also?

2.) why was $sql split? why not have the $sql out of the if already with " WHERE status = ?"

And the rest of the PHP page is here:

> ```
> <?php # Exercise solution 1
>
> $employees = '';
> $execute = array();
> $options = array(0,1);
>
> $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=eshop;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
> $sql = "SELECT firstName,lastName FROM employees";
>
> if(isset($_GET['status']) && in_array($_GET['status'], $options)){
>   $sql .= " WHERE status = ?";
>   $execute = array($_GET['status']);
> }
>
> $query = $db->prepare($sql);
> $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
> $query->execute($execute);
> $result = $query->fetchAll();
>
> foreach($result as $row){
>
>   $employees .= "{$row->firstName} {$row->lastName}<br/>";
>
> }
>
>
> ?>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <title>Exercise solution 1</title>
>   </head>
>
>   <body>
>
>     <strong>Employees list</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
>     <a href="1.php">All</a>&nbsp;
>     <a href="1.php?status=1">Status Active</a>&nbsp;
>     <a href="1.php?status=0">Status Not Active</a>
>     <br/><br/>
>     <div class="result-list"><?= $employees; ?></div>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: @FuzzyTree: nope, it doesn't. it's an outright syntax error. I'm guessing it's supposed to be `isset()`

Comment: Since you can never be sure what data you get from a client you have to check first if some data you expect actually was sent: `if(isset($_GET['status']))` only then can you actually use it.

Comment: I have an error there too, thats why im TOTALLY confused here, it's from our exercise answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you're missing a function here probably `in_array`

```
in_array($_GET['status'], $options)
```

`$options` would contain all valid possible values that `status` could have

Comment: absolutely, fixed it. Questions still stand though... thanks fuzzy.

Comment: @erezT status is verified against options probably in order to prevent the user from setting the status to something not allowed and selecting data they're not allowed to

Answer (score 3):

It's making the `where` clause conditional. If that particular query parameter isn't set, the query is simply `SELECT everything`. Otherwise it becomes `SELECT just the one specific record`.